# How to set a title attribute of a form button (not having an id) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I have a `<button>` inside a `<form>`. The button has no `id` attribute, but the form has, and I want to use JavaScript to add a `title` attribute to the button.

I tried using `querySelector` but I cannot get it to work. The code is below:

```
<form id='largerView' action='#' method='get'>
  <button>Large Version</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#largerView>button').title = 'View the larger version of the image';
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: It says it has no errors. But when I hover over the button, the title is not displayed.

Comment: Have you tried the the `setAttribute()` method.

    `button.setAttribute('title', 'View the larger version of the image');`

Comment: In that case, are you sure your JS code is executed?

Comment: Yes, sorry everything is fine. It appears clearing the browser cache solved the problem, and the title is now displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This code adds a **title** attribute to the first button that appears as a child in the form element.

```
var form = document.getElementById("largerView");
var button = form.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
button.setAttribute("title", "TITLE");
```

Further if you would like to continue using querySelector all you have to do is replace **>** with a space.

```
document.querySelector('#largerView button').title = 'View the larger version of the image';
```

Let me know if you need further help. Cheers.